# Why can't I fetch all rows from database instead of just a single entry?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have tried to get all rows from a specific table 'comments' but I get no response. I can pull a specific row based on 'id' but not all rows. I am trying to fetch all entries and return them as a json response. This code works for other tables but not for this specific table and I have no idea why. Here's what I have tried:

This works for retrieving a specific row by 'id':

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include_once("config.php");

$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE sid=".$_GET['sid']);

$array;
while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

$array[]=$result;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

But if I try this for all rows, I get a blank response:

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include_once("config.php");

$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comments");

$array;
while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

$array[]=$result;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: You're probably running out of memory. Check your server's error log.

Comment: That was my first thought but no errors in server log :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing the rows as you pull them from the database instead of putting them into an array to print later.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comments");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo json_encode($row);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: *face palm* smh. That worked. I should've seen that one. :/ Thank you though.

Comment: Glad I could help! It's usually easier to print the information as you pull it instead of putting it into an array and then printing. Keep things simple!

Comment: Why should anyone "try this"? What did you change, and why? A good answer always includes an explanation of what was changed!

Comment: That's a good point Qirel, thank you. I'm quite new to stackoverflow, I'm still trying to get the hang of it :)

Comment: It depends on what you need to do with the data. Putting it all into an array, then encoding that is not wrong and is usually the preferred way to do it, as you would create a multdimentional array instead of many separate ones.

Comment: The particular use for my case is to present the array in json format for an Android api

Comment: @EvanEdwards although this works in my development environment without fail, I get a 500 error when publishing to my server. Server doesn't give any insight in logs. Any ideas?

Comment: What webserver are you using? And did you copy the file directly over or rewrite it? 500 is a very generic error that can be caused by a lot of things (such as incorrect syntax.)

Comment: I used Filezilla to transfer the file(s) over to my server. GoDaddy, Plesk server

Comment: Check your database information again to make sure you entered it right. Are you using your own database server or one Go Daddy provides?

Comment: One GoDaddy provides. I've checked database schema and code. Everything is as it should be.

Comment: [Here's](http://curtrostudios.com/DA_Admin/all_comments.php) the link if you want to take a look.

Comment: @SteveC. Did you chmod the files to allow all_comments.php to read config.php?